# outlook rule doesn't copy email to a folder if keyword is in subject

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, office365

When any email to be has "RECEIPT" in the subject, I want my rule to copy it to my Outlook folder: "RECEIPTS".

The emails in Inbox are not copied into folder RECEIPTS if I run all the rules or even
if I run only the "Copy RECEIPT subject to RECEIPTS".

However, the other "Copy" rules work ok.

[image]

Comment: Check if the rule acts on the Inbox, or delete it and recreate a new rule.